# Вживання "з...по..." і "з...до..."

Tags: прикметники

Чи є різниця між "з...по..." і "з...до..." ?

Наприклад якщо сказати: "Фестиваль пройде з 18 до 21 грудня" / "Фестиваль пройде з 18 по 21 грудня"
То 21 числа буде фестиваль чи він вже вже закінчиться (тобто це означає включно з 21 чи 21 вже закінчиться) ?

Також, будь-ласка, вкажіть ресурс з якого Ви використовуєте правило (лінк на правило)

Answer (score 1):

"З...по..." позначає включно і початок і кінець часового проміжку, тобто вказує на період, який включає обидві дати, включно з останньою. Наприклад, "фестиваль пройде з 18 по 21 грудня" означає, що фестиваль почнеться 18 грудня і закінчиться 21 грудня включно.

У свою чергу, "з...до..." позначає період між двома датами, проте не включає останню дату. Тобто, "фестиваль пройде з 18 до 21 грудня" означає, що фестиваль почнеться 18 грудня і закінчиться 20 грудня, але не буде проходити 21 грудня.

Нажаль з посиланням не маю змоги допомогти.